# To count the number of lines only when particular characters are present - Python

Tags: python, text, character, text-files, sentence

I am having a text file(consider it as main.txt) which has multiple language contents and I am having a charcter set text file which has particular characters.
For example: character set text file contains

```
e
f
g
h
```

I want to count the number of lines in main.txt which contains anyone of the character in the character set. If a line in main.txt contains `e` or `f` or `g` or `h`, then that line should be counted as 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
with open('main.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "e" in line or "f" in line or "g" in line or "h" in line:
            count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Is there any quick way to do this process for large files. I have 30GB text file(main.txt). I want to write out the lines containing these characters into new text file in a efficient way(less time)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.